# Ansible SSH error - Node getting scaled down (behind AWS ELB) before code is deployed

Tags: ssh, deployment, ansible, amazon-elb

I am currently facing an issue during ansible rolling deployment as mentioned below:-

1. Generating dynamic inventory and passing the file to deployment playbook.
2. Before deployment some of the nodes are getting scaled down (auto scaling policy) and  hence ansible is throwing ssh error for that error.
3. Ansible is skipping the remaining nodes in the host inventory files and getting terminated.

Is there any way to skip the specific node (which is getting scaled down during deployment) and continue the deployment process with other nodes in inventory file?

Thank you for your time !.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you should try ansible dynamic inventory so that it will automatically fetch the inventory on the basis of tags at realtime.

> Ref:
>   http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_dynamic_inventory.html

2. You can try running the same playbook for the hosts which are pending using `--limit` option, in case you want to rerun your playbook for the rest of the hosts.

> Example: ansible-playbook --limit @/some-path/site.retry

3. You can consider `ignore_errors: yes` in your tasks which are failing for any reason. This will let playboook continue for rest of the hosts.

> Ref:
>   http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_error_handling.html